# Dividing frequency of a variable to create a new dataframe

Tags: r

I have four habitats and three sites per habitat, twelve sites over all.
I want to get the mean frequency of species per habitat type i.e. I want to divide the frequency by three (the number of sites per habitat). I need to create a new dataframe using Habitat, Species and Mean Frequency to be used in ggplot.

Not all species are present in each site so I do not think I can use the variable site.

My dataset looks like this

```
 Habitat    Site    Species    Frequency
   A         A1         T           3
   A         A2         T           4
   A         A3         U           5
   B         B2         V           12
   C         C2         V           3
   D         D3         X           2
```

I have tried using

```
Mean_Frequency<-df[,4]/3
```

This divides column four (frequency) by three but does not contain variables habitat and species.

Answer (score 0):

If you juste want to add a column equal to Frequency / 3 to the data:

```
df$Mean_Frequency <- df$Frequency / 3
```

If you want to calculate the average of frequency for each Species per habitats:

```
library(data.table)    
setDT(df)[, .(Mean_Frequency = mean(Frequency)), .(Habitat, Species)]
```